# Google ad words - как получить критерии таргетинга

Tags: php, google-adwords

например, добавить новый можно как то так:

```
$criterion = new AdGroupCriterion();
$criterion->setAdGroupId($campaignGroup->getId());
$criterion->setCriterion(new Gender($genders[$genderName]));

$operation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operation->setOperand($criterion);

$adGroupCriterionService->mutate([$operation]);
```

Но изменить уже выбранный нельзя, можно только добавить или удалить. Но для того что бы удалить, например, выбранный критерий пола мне надо получить тот который уже есть, то же самое и с возрастом.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $gendersQuery = $adGroupCriterionService->query('SELECT GenderType');

    $genders = [];
    foreach ($gendersQuery->getEntries() as $entry) {
        if ($entry->getCriterion()->getType() === CriterionType::GENDER) {
            $genders[] = $entry->getCriterion()->getId();
        }
    }
```